# Xamarin's XDocument doesn't save files

Tags: xamarin.android, linq-to-xml

According to [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save/p/System.String/) document, Xamarin should be able to write files in personal storage of application. Problem is, I used both XDocument.Save(string path) and XMLWriter to save my XML data to a file, but nothing happens! No Error but the file is not created either.
If you use another path, an exception will be thrown that you don't have access to that space, which means the code tries to write the file, but when you give it a legal space, it doesn't write anything.
I use:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

to get my path and then add "/file.xml" to it. I give this path to

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument();
doc = XDocument.Parse("<names></names>");
doc.Save(path);
```

I tried this solution in windows and it works but not in Xamarin.Android

Answer (score 0):

As for Saving, I was able to do it after giving my app `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. However it seems odd...since I could write files through `File.WriteAllText` in the same place...and my code never threw any exception about illegal access or whatever.
After this problem, another odd thing happened. XDocument.Save wrote the file, but later when it wanted to load it, threw exception about "XML Declaration"...the odd part is, XDocument.Save itself writes that part automatically and it can't be wrong!When I checked the file, it was completely OK.
So, I conclude that either XDocument is buggy in Xamarin (since I used the exact code in windows without any problem) or my android device is buggy. Either scenarios are unlikely.